# Sitecore ECM - Unsubscribe from newsletter

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms, sitecore-ecm

i'm using Sitecore ECM to handle the newsletter subscribtion, what i want to know are if there are a way to unsubscribe a user from the newsletter through the code -not the unsubscribe link on the sent email-.

i found this function from Sitecore.EmailCampaign.dll

```
ClientApi.Unsubsribe(string campaignEventId)
```

but it's asking for a campaign event id which i'm not sure where to find. Looking into the Sitecore ECM documentation also does not provide this information. And i would prefer i don't have to query the database directly to get the id

I'm sure there's much easier way to do this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try TargetAudience.Unsubscribe().

Comment: hey Ivan, i've take a quick look at your suggestion and it seems you might be right on this. I'll have a try again on Monday and let you know how it goes